# Fetch image from library and change image every 30 seconds in sharepoint and show slideshow with programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, picture-library, soap, image-display

I write some codes to reach library with SOAP. I can reach the list items.But I cannot process data. Actually I can do it with REST. But I don't know how to do this. I need detailed code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve list items using below:

```
 function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
var queryPayload = {  
           'query' : {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                  'ViewXml' : viewXml  
           }
};
return executeJson(url,"POST",null,queryPayload);
}


 function getListViewItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
 {
 var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
 return executeJson(url).then(
     function(data){         
         var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
         return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
     });
  }
```

where

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
method = method || 'GET';
headers = headers || {};
headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
if(method == "POST") {
    headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
}      
var ajaxOptions = 
{       
   url: url,   
   type: method,  
   contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
   headers: headers
};
if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
  ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
}  
return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
 }
```

Usage:

```
  getListViewItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'ListName','ViewName')
 .done(function(data)
 {
 var items = data.d.results;
 for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
     console.log(items[i].Title);//Process items
 }    
 })
  .fail(
   function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

Comment: Forgive me for this basic question. Where can i write "mylistname"  or GUID to fetch data ?

Comment: here: getListViewItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'ListName','ViewName')